# Sharing state between client and server in Next's

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side, next.js13

#### Summary

Project Structure:

```
app/
    [rsid]
        [categorySlug]
            [subCategorySlug]
                page.tsx
            layout.tsx
            template.tsx
            error.tsx
            loading.tsx
```

What I want to do:

I am fetching data dynamically inside page.tsx (server-side) using params.rsid. The data is a list of items and page.tsx defaults to display the first item in the list.

I fetch the same data inside layout.tsx and pass it to a client component heading.tsx. The heading.tsx component displays a dropdown menu of all the items in the list. When clicked, it should update page.tsx to show the selected item.

In other words, I want to display John, when John is selected from the dropdown menu and so on.

Are there any patterns that I should follow to achieve this? Than you in advance!

#### Additional information

A visual example the code can be found here [Github codespace](https://mogu4419868-automatic-xylophone-96r5vw7jqjq29vj4.github.dev) or here [Github Repo](https://github.com/Mogu4419868/temp)